# How can I download all my Google content?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, export

I have a school account which is about to be deleted because I graduated. I would still like to keep all the files in drive (including those I own and those shared with me), all the emails, etc. I could find an option about transferring content to another account but this is 'disabled by the administrator,' possibly because the destination account is not in my organization. for Google Drive but while I still have access to all my content, how can I permanently archive them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should contact your school account administrator / support as there are options for schools account that administrators manage.

#### Reference

##### Google Accounts Help Center

- [Copy content from your school account to another account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6386856?sjid=2369476213504804128-NA)

##### Google Workspace Help Center

- [Let graduating students transfer data](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6364687?hl=en)